# How to Time Stamp Data to do Day Over Day Comparison

Tags: python, time, automation, analysis

All,
I am trying to look at trends over time with my data. However, all of the data I have is static (snapshot in time). Therefore, I do not have any way to track how long something has been in inventory for. I know that I could export the data, and then save it to a table for the report to reference, but that is manual and manual tasks introduce errors. Therefore, I am looking to automate it. I am experienced in VBA but new to Python, so would this be possible by creating a python scrip to write a CSV file with a date timestamp and then pull that CSV file back into the Power bi report?

If this is possible to do without coding, that would be great. I am open to any and all ideas.
Thanks,
Brian

Comment: The PowerQuery editor in Power BI is explicitly designed to prepare your data for analysis. Why would you use an additional tool?

Comment: This isn't a power bi question so I'm removing the tag. For the record, data accumulation is not possible in PBI and you'll need to store that externally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.